What is this recent movie set in Ireland featuring a man returning to his village?
Saw a movie; I think was set in Ireland, about 5-6 months ago on Netflix streaming, but cannot find on my list of viewed movies.
Man returns to his smaller village.  A shy and somewhat outcast lad from a very large family begins to work building a fence for him.  I think there were some property rights issue in the movie and the young man becomes a hero of sorts, and gains the attention of a girl he liked but went unnoticed by her.  Movie was 1-3 years old; may have been an independent.  No one famous that I know of in the movie, maybe small budget.  Family drama.  No violence.

Possibly Stay from 2013, though I'm not sure it all fits.

Did one of the characters write greeting card messages?

Not Stay, but thanks for suggestion.

I don't recall any greeting cards, but could just not remember it.  Suggestions?

There was a movie I saw a fed years ago that fit a lot of your description. The man was a pig farmer, and there were a few jokes from his childhood sweetheart about how bad he smelled. But, I can't remember the title of the film...

No, thanks, but definitely not that.  The focus was more about the kid if I can remember correctly.  This man who had returned to his village (his onetime family home) and he was a writer or some such.

HUGE apologies to "Wait"  from two days ago.  You are CORRECT!!!!!  SO SORRY.  I re-reviewed the movie and you nailed it with your comment.  Very astute of you.  Thank you so much.  This was driving me crazy.  I can see how my memory played havoc since I was focused more on the plight of the boy than on the main story.

Sorry, only saw this comment now. Glad you found it; I'll put it up.

@BenPlont That was "Waking Ned Devine" but the rest of the story doesn't match. Pig Finn and Maggie stayed at the village all the time, the outsider was the Lotto man.

@his no, the movie I'm thinking about wasn't Ned Devine. The movie I'm thinking about came out only 2 or 3 years ago.

@BenPlont Then I would like to see that as a separate question, I would like to watch that movie.

You're looking for the 2013 drama Stay about the 2 stories of a couple taking some time apart with her returning to Canada and him staying in Ireland. In his story, the man (Aidan Quinn) hires a young boy to build a fence around his property. Here's the trailer:



